# CSS: how to clear a float

Tags: css

I'd like to add some text to the bottom of the 6 images on [this page](http://www.aquariussupport.com.au/).

There is HTML:

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_165" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_165" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/bookkeeping-services"><img class="wp-image-165 size-medium" title="Bookkeeping Services Perth" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Bookkeeping-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Bookkeeping Services Perth" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_165" class="wp-caption-text">Bookkeeping Services Perth.</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_166" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_166" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/administration-support"><img class="wp-image-166 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Bookkeeping-Support-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Bookkeeping Training &amp; Support" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_166" class="wp-caption-text">Bookkeeping Training &amp; Support</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_167" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_167" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><img class="wp-image-167 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Administration-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Administration Support Services Perth" width="164" height="300">
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_167" class="wp-caption-text">Administration Support Services Perth</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_168" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_168" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/hr-support"><img class="wp-image-168 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/HR-Support-380-1-164x300.jpg" alt="Human Resources Support and Services Perth" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_168" class="wp-caption-text">Human Resources Support and Services Perth</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_169" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_169" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/website-enhancement-and-search-engine-optimisation"><img class="wp-image-169 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/website-seo&amp;enhancement-380-164x300.jpg" alt="website seo &amp; enhancement" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_169" class="wp-caption-text">Website SEO &amp; Enhancement</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_170" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_170" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/occupational-health-safety"><img class="wp-image-170 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Occupational-Health-and-Safety-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Occupational Health and Safety Services Perth" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_170" class="wp-caption-text">Occupational Health and Safety Services Perth</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <p class="clear"><small>BAS Agent<br>
      Xero Partner<br>
      Member of the Institute of Bookkeepers</small></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The text that is not clearing the images is:

```
<small>BAS Agent<br>
   Xero Partner<br>
   Member of the Institute of Bookkeepers</small>
```

The CSS is:

```
.onesixth {width: 15%; float: left; margin-right: 1%; display: inline-block;}

.wp-caption.alignnone {
    margin: 1.25em 20px 20px 0;
}
.wp-caption{
   position: relative;
}
.wp-caption img,
.wp-caption-text{
   position: absolute;
}
.wp-caption img{
   top: 60px;
   left: 0px;
}
.wp-caption-text {
   top:0;
   min-height: 56px;
}
figure, figcaption, img {
    margin: 0;
}
.clear {clear: both;}
```

How do I make sure `<div class="clear"></div>` just above this works properly?

Or, how do I ensure the `<small>` displays underneath the 1st image?

Thanks.

Comment: Provide your CSS for the `.clear` class.

Comment: add your css code also, or try clear : both

Answer (score 1):

**Your CSS for `.clear` class should be like this,**

```
.clear:before,
.clear:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clear:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

[Check this out for your reference](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Comment: Surely this CSS clearfix ought to be applied to `.entry-content` rather than to `.clear`? The clearfix obviates the need for `<div class="clear"></div>`.

Answer (score 1):

I have added some test `css` to the markup you have provided in your example, in which shows the `.clear` is working the way it is supposed to.

**N.B.** You *only* need apply `.clear` to the paragraph - you don't need to include an empty `<div>` before the `<p>`.

```css
.onesixth {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin: 6px 12px 6px 0;
border: 1px solid rgb(255,0,0);
}

.onesixth, figure, figcaption, img {
width: 164px;
}

figure, figcaption, img {
margin: 0;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_165" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_165" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/bookkeeping-services"><img class="wp-image-165 size-medium" title="Bookkeeping Services Perth" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Bookkeeping-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Bookkeeping Services Perth" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_165" class="wp-caption-text">Bookkeeping Services Perth.</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_166" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_166" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/administration-support"><img class="wp-image-166 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Bookkeeping-Support-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Bookkeeping Training &amp; Support" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_166" class="wp-caption-text">Bookkeeping Training &amp; Support</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_167" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_167" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><img class="wp-image-167 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Administration-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Administration Support Services Perth" width="164" height="300">
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_167" class="wp-caption-text">Administration Support Services Perth</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_168" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_168" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/hr-support"><img class="wp-image-168 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/HR-Support-380-1-164x300.jpg" alt="Human Resources Support and Services Perth" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_168" class="wp-caption-text">Human Resources Support and Services Perth</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_169" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_169" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/website-enhancement-and-search-engine-optimisation"><img class="wp-image-169 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/website-seo&amp;enhancement-380-164x300.jpg" alt="website seo &amp; enhancement" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_169" class="wp-caption-text">Website SEO &amp; Enhancement</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_170" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_170" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/occupational-health-safety"><img class="wp-image-170 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Occupational-Health-and-Safety-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Occupational Health and Safety Services Perth" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_170" class="wp-caption-text">Occupational Health and Safety Services Perth</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>

  <p class="clear"><small>BAS Agent<br>
    Xero Partner<br>
    Member of the Institute of Bookkeepers</small></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rounin. I've added `<p class="clear">` but the issue remains.

Comment: Do you also see the issue in the snippet in the answer above? If so, what browser are you using? (Hang in there - we'll get to the bottom of this!)

Comment: No, the snippet works fine. I'm using Chrome to view the [live site](http://www.aquariussupport.com.au/).

Comment: Okay. Where you have: `<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="onesixth">
<p class="clear"><small>BAS Agent<br />
Xero Partner<br />
Member of the Institute of Bookkeepers</small></p>
</div>` remove `<div class="clear"></div>`, remove `<div class="onesixth">` and remove the final `</div>`.

Comment: Thanks. Done. I can see the text now, but it is behind the first caption and first image. I need to wrap it with `<div class="onesixth"></div>` so that I can add other text below other images.

Comment: Thanks. I want it to clear all the `.onesixth` elements above it, not `.entry-content`.

Comment: Sorry - I got confused (ignore me!) Have another look at the snippet above - the final `<p>` _is_ inside `.entry-content` and it does clear all the floated `divs`.

Comment: Yes, I know the snippet works, I can't get it working on the site though.

Comment: Check to see if there are any other discrepancies (like the ones I mentioned above) between the markup and the styles on the live site and the markup and the styles in the snippet above.

Comment: The only difference I can see in the CSS on the live site is `.onesixth {margin: 6px 12px 6px 0;}`. If I add that to the live site, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use `clear:both` or you could enclose all image divs (`.onesixth`) inside a parent div(`.fixit`)

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="fixit">
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_165" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_165" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/bookkeeping-services"><img class="wp-image-165 size-medium" title="Bookkeeping Services Perth" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Bookkeeping-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Bookkeeping Services Perth" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_165" class="wp-caption-text">Bookkeeping Services Perth.</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_166" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_166" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/administration-support"><img class="wp-image-166 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Bookkeeping-Support-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Bookkeeping Training &amp; Support" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_166" class="wp-caption-text">Bookkeeping Training &amp; Support</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_167" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_167" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><img class="wp-image-167 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Administration-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Administration Support Services Perth" width="164" height="300">
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_167" class="wp-caption-text">Administration Support Services Perth</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_168" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_168" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/hr-support"><img class="wp-image-168 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/HR-Support-380-1-164x300.jpg" alt="Human Resources Support and Services Perth" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_168" class="wp-caption-text">Human Resources Support and Services Perth</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_169" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_169" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/website-enhancement-and-search-engine-optimisation"><img class="wp-image-169 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/website-seo&amp;enhancement-380-164x300.jpg" alt="website seo &amp; enhancement" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_169" class="wp-caption-text">Website SEO &amp; Enhancement</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="onesixth">
    <figure id="attachment_170" aria-labelledby="figcaption_attachment_170" class="wp-caption alignnone" style="width: 164px"><a href="/services/occupational-health-safety"><img class="wp-image-170 size-medium" src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Occupational-Health-and-Safety-380-164x300.jpg" alt="Occupational Health and Safety Services Perth" width="164" height="300"></a>
      <figcaption id="figcaption_attachment_170" class="wp-caption-text">Occupational Health and Safety Services Perth</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  </div>
  <p><small>BAS Agent<br>
    Xero Partner<br>
    Member of the Institute of Bookkeepers</small></p>
</div>
```

and apply the following CSS to `.fixit`

```
.fixit:after{visibility:hidden;display:block;font-size:0;content:" ";clear:both;height:0;}
    .fixit{display:inline-block;clear:both;}
    * html .fixit{height:1%;}
    .fixit{display:block;}
```

Comment: This answer is formatted so un-helpfully that it must have been copied from somewhere. Please provide a citation.

Comment: And what is the rule `clear:.req-a-quote input[type="submit"]both;` supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @this-vidor Yeah it was copied from one of my projects. I no longer write that fixing the floats part from scratch .I did that mistake in hurry by copying it wrong. Its `clear:both;` and not `clear:.req-a-quote input[type="submit"]both;`. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Will remove the down-vote if you fix up the answer! What would be *extra* useful would be an explanation of why it works.

Comment: Updated my answer. Will improve more after reaching home.